# Angularjs, Ivh-tree : Angularjs digest cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch, angularjs-digest

I am switching between two arrays which eventually form an ivh-treeview is taking significant time; both the arrays differ by 1000 elements, i load the data into the arrays initially once the page is loaded by restangular requests to the json. After profiling the change data request, using
Profile->Flare Chart, I see a repeated cycle of $scope.apply(),$scope and $digest. How do i reduce this time ? or probably can we skip this cycle of apply()/digest() since I know for sure that there is no implied data dependency?

Below is the link to the flare chart image  with the delay between 3 ms to 8 ms:

[image]

Comment: to display this arrays are you using a ui-grid? are you using pagination?

Comment: @Radu i am displaying the arrays via an angular module - ivh tree view on two different divs.